# How do I install ia32-libs-multiarch

Tags: 64-bit

I'm trying to install ia32-libs-multiarch but I get the following error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ibus-gtk:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libaudio2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libcupsimage2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgail-common:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libgtk2.0-0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-opengl:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-qt3support:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-scripttools:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt4-svg:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtgui4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libxaw7:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: xaw3dg:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: This isn't a dupe. The problem is more specific and has unique aspects that aren't present in the generic "unmet dependencies" issue.

Comment: I managed to solve my root problem (getting Android SDK to run) by installing libc6-i386 libstdc++6:i386

Comment: Could you post that as answer?

Comment: I could but it's the answer to a different question. I could change the question but I think it still has value as is. I'm surely not the only one who was unable to install the package.

Comment: Did you also install the ia32-libs package?  That's needed too.